# Error inflating class NavigationView caused by ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-appcompat, androidx

So around 1% of my daily users are haunted with the NavigationView exception which is caused by an image resource not being found. I find that strange, 99% of other users are just fine. I was hoping that updating my dependancies in version iterations will resolve the issue itself, but unfortunately, this error has stayed in my Crashlytics logs for 6 iterations already and it's the worst crash that is affecting my users.

The obvious thing would be that it is specific to older devices, but this would be a wrong assumption. It is not device specific, neither version specific. Although some specifics can be pointed out

- Android Version

  - 90% Andorid 8
  - 10% Android 7
- Device

  - Huawei 50%
  - Samsung 50%

Two relevant dependancies i'm using:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

The relevant piece of code in the XML layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_drawer_header2"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

The Header layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/authWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    tools:layout_width="240dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/car"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/driver"
        tools:text="#01" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/driverIcon"
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/driver"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/number"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/driver"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person_white_24dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/driver"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/driverIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Drivers name" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/coDriverIcon"
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/codriver"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/number"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/codriver"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person_white_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/codriver"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/coDriverIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/driver"
        tools:text="Co-Driver name" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/carIcon"
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/car"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/number"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/car"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_car_white_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/car"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/carIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/codriver"
        tools:text="Racing Car" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_account_circle_white_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_log_out" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/switchText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="@string/track_me_on_racelivemaps_com"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/trackingOn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/number" />


    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/trackingOn"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"

        android:maxLines="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/switchText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/switchText" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/active_stage"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switchText" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/activeStage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView12" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:title="@string/mode">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/recce"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_write_black_24dp"
                    android:title="@string/reccemode" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/liaison"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_route_black_24dp"
                    android:title="@string/liaisonmode" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/racing"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_racing_flag_black_24dp"
                    android:title="@string/racemode" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/tsd"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_timer_black_24dp"
                    android:title="@string/tsd" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/tsd_advanced"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_tsd_advanced"
                    android:title="@string/tsd_advanced" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/custom_1"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_navigation_layout"
                    android:title="@string/custom_layout_1" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/custom_2"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_navigation_layout"
                    android:title="@string/custom_layout_2" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/custom_3"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_navigation_layout"
                    android:title="@string/custom_layout_3" />

            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="none">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/stages"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_stage_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/special_stages" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/settings" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/customize_ui"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_layout_edit"
            android:title="@string/customize_ui" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/weather"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_weather"
            android:title="@string/weather" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_key_white_24dp"
            android:title="@string/log_in" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/manual"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_manual"
            android:title="@string/user_manual" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/language"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_translate"
            android:title="@string/language" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/invite"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/invite" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/feedback"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_feedback_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/feedback_report_bug" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/tester"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_tester"
            android:title="@string/become_a_tester" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/policy"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_policy"
            android:title="@string/privacy_policy" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/logoff"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_key_white_24dp"
            android:title="@string/log_off" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/exit"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/exit" />


    </group>


</menu>
```

And finally the crash logs.

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Binary XML
>   file line #48: Error inflating class
>   com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3173)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3284)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1894)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7383)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
>
> Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48:
>   Binary XML file line #48: Error inflating class
>   com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
>
> Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48:
>   Error inflating class
>   com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
>
> Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Constructor.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:658)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:801)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:874)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>          at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
>          at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>          at ee.siimplangi.rallytripmeter.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:186)
>          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7358)
>          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7349)
>          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1219)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3126)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3284)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1894)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7383)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
>
> Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29:
>   Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class ImageView
>
> Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29:
>   Error inflating class ImageView
>
> Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID
>
> ## 0x7f0800a5
>
> ```
>    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:290)
>    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1476)
>    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.createDrawableIfNeeded(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:235)
>    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200)
>    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
>    at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
>    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:59)
>    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
>    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
>    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
>    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
>    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
>    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:783)
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:874)
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835)
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>    at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:207)
>    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:281)
>    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:193)
>    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:104)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Constructor.java)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:658)
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:801)
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:874)
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835)
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
>    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>    at ee.siimplangi.rallytripmeter.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:186)
>    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7358)
>    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7349)
>    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1219)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3126)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3284)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1894)
>    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109)
>    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7383)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469)
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
> ```

Comment: The drawable `ic_person_white_24dp` can't be found. Maybe it is inside a folder like `drawable-v24` and not in the main `drawable folder?`

Comment: @forpas This is not the case, but you have pointed out something that might fix the problem. Im issuing a new build in a few moments and will report the results back. The ic_person_white_24dp is not a vector drawable but instead bitmap drawable (e.g. each for xxxdpi, mdpi etc). So I will try to chane app:srcCompat to android:src and see what happens.

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue regressed, so the comment above is not a solution.

Comment: Try to find out what `7f0800a5` id corresponds to in `R.java` class. That would give you seams as to which drawable is problematic.

Comment: [visit here hope this works in your case also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73740231/13560080)

Answer (score 5):

after reading the comments , first of all you have to use `android:src` because you are not using vector drawable.

This problem occur when we paste image from explorer to **drawable** folder then it ask whether to copy **drawable** or **drawable-v24** and if you have pasted images in both directory structures, or have one more images with different directory structure then it will show this error, make sure to delete the icon from **drawable-v24** after moving it to **drawable** folder , and clean the project and then run it will work .

Comment: Are you sure he's not using a vector? And this issue only effects a small percent of users, cleaning and rebuilding doesn't effect it as there is no error on the developer's machine.

Comment: yeaah this is what he said in the comment on the question :The ic_person_white_24dp is not a vector drawable but instead bitmap drawable

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't see that comment. I also have a bitmap and use `app:srcCompat` so maybe that's my issue too.

Comment: Yeah android:src for non vector drawable

Comment: I tried this in my personal project, sadly the issue persists.

Comment: Oh man, you saved my day!  But still don't get it why AS places .png drawables into v.2x folder?

Comment: I had the same issue. I had to refactor/rename the file in order to successfully build.