# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView after migration to AndroidX

Tags: android, androidx, android-navigationview

After I updated my project to `AndroidX` with `targetSdkVersion` set to 28, my project crashes when installing it from the store for beta testing.

The following is the error log I receive:

```
2019-07-08 08:28:33.026 32011-32011/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: hu.itq.oakprotection, PID: 32011
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hu.itq.oakprotection/hu.itq.oakprotection.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3302)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:658)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:801)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:874)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.c(Unknown Source:23)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(Unknown Source:4)
            at hu.itq.oakprotection.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:6)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7372)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3147)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3302)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
         Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method d()I in class Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
            at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater.a(Unknown Source:5)
            at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(Unknown Source:25)
            at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.b(Unknown Source:12)
            at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(Unknown Source:255)
            at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(Unknown Source:2)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
```

The following are my dependencies in `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    def versionMajor = 1
    def versionMinor = 0
    def versionPatch = 1
    def versionBuild = 4 // ezt kell átírni új verzió kirakásakor

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "hu.itq.oakprotection"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 1000 + versionPatch * 100 + versionBuild
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'

    implementation 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    //Test error miatt kellett
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'

    //Aszinkron hálózatokhoz
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

    //Facebook
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'
    //Osm Droid
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.MKergall:osmbonuspack:6.4'

    implementation 'com.github.angads25:filepicker:1.1.1'
    //Tile provider igényli
    implementation 'mil.nga.geopackage:geopackage-android:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.1'
    implementation 'mil.nga.geopackage:geopackage-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'ar.com.hjg:pngj:2.1.0'
    implementation 'mil.nga:tiff:2.0.0'
    implementation('mil.nga.geopackage:geopackage-android:3.0.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services'
        exclude group: 'com.google.maps.android', module: 'android-maps-utils'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v13'
    }
    //Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    //Mapsforge rendering and database support, which is LGPL
    implementation 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android:0.8.0'
    implementation 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map:0.8.0'
    implementation 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-themes:0.8.0'
    // ExoPlayer
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.7.3'
    //Youtube
    implementation 'com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:v1.7.0'}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorWhite"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Why am I receiving an `android.view.InflateException` error for `NavigationView`?

Comment: Are you using any views from the 3rd party libraries? (just a guess)

Comment: check `layout/nav_header_main`

Comment: In my case was... `android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"  ` .
Works in previos sdk versión but now...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are multiple reasons why this error can occur. Check the following and make sure they are proper:

- Check your code for `drawable` and `color` resources used inside the `com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView` you've used, probably in `activity_main.xml`, if you're using the default Navigation Drawer template code from Android Studio.
- Check that the drawable files are in `res/drawable` folder, not in `res/drawable-v21`.
- Check if you've used `android:backgroundTint()` or `android:src` or similar inside your `NavigationView`. Since they don't work below android API Level 21, use `app:backgroundTint` or `app:srcCompat` instead.

Comment: The problem was:
android: backgroundTint = "@ color / colorWhite".
Solution:
app: backgroundTint = "@ color / colorWhite"
Thank you, you saved my day ;)

Comment: Glad I could help you! These are the 3 usual suspects that I always look for when encountered with this error.

Comment: i have same issue 
1) I am not using backgrounTint or android:src
2) I am not using color or drawable in NavigationView
but my application crash on this line
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_base_activity);

Comment: @MuhammadTufail, then it must have been something else which is the cause of the crash. What's the error log saying?  Did you ask any separate question, I can't seem to find it on your profile.

Comment: Thanks for the reply no i didn't ask any separate question.
My error is same 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
All androidx dependencies are added i recheck my code 5-6 time.
I also remove all the drawable and colour for testing but app crash again..

Comment: @MuhammadTufail Then please ask a new question & post your entire code on your `NavigationView`, error log and check you've implemented/migrated to AndroidX correctly.

Comment: If i ask new question then developer will say duplicate question.

Comment: @MuhammadTufail post the links in the 1st paragraph to mention your research efforts, put codes and express that you've not found a solution

Comment: You're welcome @MD.Riyaz. Glad my answer solved your problem as well. Do consider giving an upvote since it helped.

Comment: this answer saved my day

Comment: Happy to help @YashM.Hanj

Comment: This helped me track down my issue. The errors made me look somewhere else but this one help me get back on track. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

For those who the chosen answer didn't help them, I've found that had a problem with NavigationView theme and it should be an appCompat theme  (at least for me).
after creating a new style like:

```
<style name="NavView" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    ...
</style>
```

and used it with android:theme="@style/NavView" in NavigationView in my mainactivity.xml, the app runs perfectly now.

Comment: Changed theme to  'android:theme="@style/Widget.Design.NavigationView"' and it works :)

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the issue is in `navigation.NavigationView` `app:headerLayout` layout I am setting:

```
<ImageView
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
```

and the problem is with `ic_launcher_round` because this is inside folder `mipmap-anydpi-v26` and I am using Android version 7.1.1 is API Level: 25. I hope this helps anyone

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was the theme value in the Manifest file

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.BarcodeReaderDrawerActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_barcode_reader_drawer">
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme.NoActionBar"
    </activity>
```

Changed in

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.BarcodeReaderDrawerActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_barcode_reader_drawer"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

`android.view.InflateException:` means there is something wrong in your XML file itself. Please check all your **dimensions**, **color resources**, and **other resources** you have assigned in the XML tag. Or post your XML file here.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your XML file. Something wrong in your xml like menu, nav header and other. In my Case, wrong in res/menu/menu.xml

Answer (score 1):

I had this error during upgrade to Androidx, it was hard to find. The problem was with the activity theme.

In styles.xml, somehow I had the wrong android material theme, and it was causing the navigation bar not be attached to the action bar.

```
from:

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">

to:

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried changing module settings, gradle settings, changing dependencies and many thing and found the issue is with the navigation view, But a different kind of issue i.e.

**The image choosen for drawer layout is overflowed -> so just change the image or edit it resize it and then try.**

So because of that the Navigation View throws error in some devices.

Answer (score 1):

This error is related to the theme. I solved my problem by commenting the following line from the theme

```
  <style name="AppTheme.NavigationView"  >
    <!--<item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FFFFFF</item>-->
    <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
</style>
```

By removing or commenting line by line on the theme code, you can quickly conclude where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this helps. Hope this answer helps someone facing an issue

```
 <style name="Theme.PLCDrive" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

in my case when the theme style was MaterialComponents it keeps crashing and as I changed to AppCompat error resolved and works

```
<style name="Theme.PLCDrive" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I manually moved everything in `res/drawable-v24` to `res/drawable` folder and `res/mipmap-anydpi-v26` to `res/mipmap-hdpi` and problem was solved in phones with Android 5 and 6.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was not because of `android:src`

but because I was using a vector gradient as the background(            `android:background="@drawable/bg"`)
inside nav header layout

and it was only happening in Android 6

I changed the vector from this:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt" android:width="200dp" android:height="133dp" android:viewportWidth="375" android:viewportHeight="280">
    <path android:pathData="M0 0h375v280H0V0z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="497.417" android:endY="263.205" android:startX="150.5" android:startY="-33.5" android:type="linear">
                <item android:color="#FFFFFFFF" android:offset="0"/>
                <item android:color="#00000000" android:offset="1"/>
            </gradient>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
</vector>
```

to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:angle="315"
        android:endColor="#ffffff"
        android:startColor="#000000"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

and the crash disapperard

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue. In my case I have put my navigation drawer menu icon inside drawable-v24 folder. This should be placed inside drawable folder. Once I moved the icons from drawable-v24 folder to drawable folder it works fine. Hopefully this will be helpful

Answer (score -1):

In my case, in the navigation header layout, I had an image that was too big and was not fitting in the screen. I changed that icon and it ran.