# Binary XML Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, androidx, material-components-android

I've checked extensively on StackOverflow & it's a frequent question but I failed to use any of the solutions to resolve my issue. I migrated my app to AndoridX and then my app started to crash after migration on `NavigationView`. However, if I comment out the code of `NavigationView`, the app is working fine. Please view all my xml codes and the error log too.
    I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56931348/error-inflating-class-com-google-android-material-navigation-navigationview-afte/56932664?noredirect=1#comment102958915_56932664) related question on the same topic but my crash is not resolved from the answers:

Layout codes:

**layout_base.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/anchor_view"
                android:layout_width="20sp"
                android:layout_height="5sp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></View>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/child"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include layout="@layout/layout_tool_bar">

                </include>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rlt_child_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navigation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/lst_menu_items"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/ll_menu_options"
                        android:dividerHeight="0.0sp"
                        android:scrollbars="none" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ll_menu_options"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/iv_powered_by"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:visibility="gone">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.5"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:visibility="invisible">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/ll_facebook"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/iv_facebook"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/ll_twitter"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:visibility="visible">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/iv_twitter"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/ll_instagram_page"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:visibility="visible">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/iv_in"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 />


                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/ll_gplus"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.5"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:visibility="invisible">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/iv_gplus"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 />

                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_powered_by"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="9dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

        </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>


        <include layout="@layout/layout_fab"></include>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The app crashes on this line: `setContentView(R.layout.layout_base_activity);`

Also I am using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` theme (check the [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58298342/binary-xml-error-inflating-class-com-google-android-material-navigation-navigati/58299078#comment102960394_58298342))

Error log:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Binary XML file line #48: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Binary XML file line #48: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
            at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.createCustomViewInternal(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:211)
            at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.access$000(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:20)
            at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater$PrivateWrapperFactory2.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:302)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:186)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
            at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
            at com.pentaloop.playerxtreme.presentation.activities.FileManagerActivity.onCreate(FileManagerActivity.java:155)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-library:1.5.8@aar'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7'
implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:3.0.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
implementation 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'
implementation 'jcifs:jcifs:1.3.17'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.jpardogo.googleprogressbar:library:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.pwittchen:reactivewifi-rx2:0.3.0'
implementation 'com.github.pwittchen:reactivenetwork-rx2:3.0.6'
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$rootProject.ext.kotlinx_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$rootProject.ext.kotlinx_version"

//Android X

implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
```

}

PS: I have looked at the possible duplicate question, and the answer for that involves the `android.support` library. However, since I am not using the support or design libraries in my code, the solution doesn't apply to me.

Comment: Which app theme are you using?

Comment: Share your app level `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @Muhammad Awais i shared the build.gradle file please check

Comment: @MuhammadTufail, is your targetSdkVersion above 28?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I am using Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar theme

Comment: @SaadAAkash my targetSdkVersion is 28

Comment: @MuhammadTufail: Error you are getting redirects that you are having issue in your XML. You have also added dependency for the Material, so I don't think your issue belongs to NavigationView. You are using two other layouts (`@layout/layout_tool_bar`, `@layout/layout_fab`) in this XML, kindly re-check them, they might have an issue which causes this error.

Comment: @Muhammad Awais I checked all the possible way. I remove the both layout layout_tool_bar and layout_fab and then run app.
app crash i don't know why. 
i have updated the libraries version java version.

Comment: Have you manually converted your libraries to AndroidX or using Android Studio ?

Comment: @MuhammadTufail Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58299078/2016562). The issue is related to `NavigationView`. The material component library requires a **Material Components Theme**.

Comment: @MuhammadTufail Also, but it is not related to the issue you can use `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `DrawerLayout`, you've used `android:drawingCacheQuality="low"`. When set to low quality, the drawing cache used a lower color depth, thus losing precision in rendering gradients, hence uses less memory. But `android:drawingCacheQuality` has been deprecated, see the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:drawingCacheQuality). Use Canvas & Pixel Api instead, programmatically. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52985554/11040422) by @mostafa-monowar for an implementation.

Comment: if i remove this line android:drawingCacheQuality="low" then the app also crash.

Comment: I didn't tell you to remove, read carefully, implement Pixel Api to achieve the same. Also, to fix the current issue, check the other 2 XML layouts or post the codes in the question that you've included in this Layout code, which are `layout_tool_bar` & `layout_fab`.

Comment: i mention in the question when i remove 
com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
app working fine

Comment: the issue is in NavigationView because when i remove this app run

Comment: @SaadAAkashi have create a Drawer in the seperate project using androidx its working fine but when i add the same code in my project the the app Crash with same error

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` theme.
As described in the [getting started](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme) doc, in your app you have to use a **Material Components Theme**.

Something like:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

using one of these:

```
Theme.MaterialComponents
Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight
Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar
```

If you cannot change your theme to inherit from a Material Components theme, you can inherit from a [Material Components **Bridge** theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#bridge-themes-bridge-themes).

Comment: Thanks for the response.
i changed the theme of my application but app crash again i think the crash is in NavigationView when i remove navigation view i don't know why application run fine without any crash or error

Comment: i have create a Drawer in the seperate project using androidx its working fine but when i add the same code in my project the the app Crash with same error