# Cannot inflate navigationview in android

Tags: android, navigationview

I cannot find out what causes this problem?
I posted loccat error logs for asking me a log. Can you please check whats wrong with that.
Appreciate your kind help!
I am trying to use navigationview in MainActivity but it crashes and gives me this kind of error:

```
Error inflating class com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuItemView


Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuItemView

Failed to resolve attribute at index 15: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0301a9 a=-1}
```

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fancy="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        fancy:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        fancy:menu="@menu/menu_main" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I came across with this logcat error when i run my mainactivity.
Logcat:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuItemView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuItemView
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NormalViewHolder.<init>(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:315)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:411)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:361)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6794)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5975)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1287)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:498)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
2020-12-07 14:12:44.435 8107-8107/com.futumap E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:758)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2484)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2200)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 15: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0301a9 a=-1}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:726)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4750)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:597)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:593)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat.<init>(LinearLayoutCompat.java:157)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ForegroundLinearLayout.<init>(ForegroundLinearLayout.java:61)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuItemView.<init>(NavigationMenuItemView.java:91)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuItemView.<init>(NavigationMenuItemView.java:87)
            ... 66 more
```

Comment: Post more of the logcat?

Comment: Added logcat.Can you check it please?

Comment: Have a look at here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56931348/error-inflating-class-com-google-android-material-navigation-navigationview-afte